# JasperServer CE Input Control Broken

Tags: javascript, jasperserver

While using a single select query list control a page is throwing some `javascript` error.

I think `javascript` is unable to handle an amount of records higher than 20000.

Am I right? If yes is there a way to handle this issue?

Is there any way to put some search page or auto complete procedure?

Answer (score 0):

To get a more helpful answer you'll need to post the actual error.

No, there are not any more clever input controls to handle large volumes of data. But it's a known enhancement idea. It's likely to be added someday. Be sure to log it on the [JasperReports Server tracker](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperserver/tracker) if you think it's important.